# Windows report add to datasource list

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I have a little problem :)
I have created entity which i want to fill and display in windows report in VS 2008.

My entity code

```
namespace MvcApplication3.entities
{
    public class invoiceRow
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname{get;set;}
        public decimal Income { get; set; }

    }
}
```

What I want to do, is get this entity displayed in datasource vindow for report, so i can pick data source(with the entity and add it to the report).
I know how to bind it but not how to get report to detect this entity.

---

I have found if i create class : with code as follows,

```
  public List<invoiceRow> rows()
    {
        List<invoiceRow> list = new List<invoiceRow>();

        return (list);
    }
```

the report will detect the entity. How ever i do not understand why?
does it have to be as it has to have data source, to display entity in report data sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your entity class. To me it works as a data source. Have you searched hard enough because I think the Data Source Configuration Wizard sorts the classes by their namespace. Here is my code:

```
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Report1.rdlc"));
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
var dataSourcesNames = (ReadOnlyCollection<string>) reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSourcesNames[0], objectCollection));//objectCollection is a List<MyObject>
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

And yes the object data source always has to be a collection. If you think it is kinda like database table (which always has multiple rows in some phase).

Comment: Dave, i have created new project, created entity and as default before i have created the function, i had only system entities to see